# Ruby on Rails - Nested Attributes, adding unwanted fields after saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, nested-attributes

My nested attribute form is adding unwanted fields automatically each time I save my regular form.

How do I prevent from adding an extra field after saving?

**registrations_controller.rb** controller

```
def edit
  @user = User.find(current_user.id)
  @profile = Profile.new
  @user.businesses.build
end
```

**business.rb** model

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :users
end
```

**user.rb** model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :businesses
end
```

**view page**

```
<%= form_for @user, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :businesses do |builders| %>
    <%= builders.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

At first it shows a single empty field, and then when I press save, it adds another one, even though if its blank or not. I just want to keep one field for now and not automatically add another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :businesses
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :businesses, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: lambda { |b| b[:name].blank? }
end
```

UPDATE:

```
@user.businesses.build if @user.businesses.empty?
```

Comment: it still adds an extra field when saving record

Comment: It should reject businesses with empty `name`.  Updated.

Comment: Oh its almost there! But why is it that if I have a value saved in the field, I can't save an empty field anymore if I decide to leave the field empty, after saving it?

Comment: If u want to add another field - use `link_to_add` and `link_to_remove helper` methods on the form builder. And remove `reject_if` if u want to save empty values in new fields.